# Type of export default in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface

I have interface for function:

```
interface FunctionType {
    (param: string): number
}
```

Then I create implementation of this interface:

```
const Function: FunctionType = (param: string) => {
    // ...
}

export default Function
```

Is there any way to specify function type without creating variable/constant?

```
// Parameter has wrong type, but there is no error, because this function has no FunctionType interface.
export default (param: number) => {

}
```

Comment: There is no syntax o specify the type of the default

Comment: How about `export interface FunctionType{...}` without `default`?